# leaflet fitbounds with a cartodb named maps

Tags: carto, carto-js

It seems that fitbounds() is not possible with named maps

```
cartodb.createLayer(map,layerSource)
    .addTo(map)
    .done(function(layer) {
        beams.addLayer(layer);
        map.fitBounds(beams, {maxZoom: 6, paddingTopLeft: [50, 70], paddingBottomRight: [50, 50]});
        map.spin(false);
    });
```

Any idea how I could use it ?

Comment: fitBounds is a leaflet method and has nothing to do with createLayer. What error do you get?

Comment: I get : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functioncartodb.js:8 (anonymous function)cartodb.js:8 e.LayerGroup.e.Class.extend.eachLayercartodb.js:8 e.FeatureGroup.e.LayerGroup.extend.getBoundscartodb.js:7 e.Map.e.Class.extend.fitBoundsmain.js:861 (anonymous function)cartodb.js:6 a.Events.triggercartodb.js:20 ccartodb.js:20 (anonymous function)cartodb.js:20 (anonymous function)cartodb.js:6 (anonymous function)

Answer (score 2):

Unless `beams` is a [length-two array of coordinate pairs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds), `fitBounds` won't work. The [function definition](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds) says:

```
fitBounds( <LatLngBounds> bounds, <fitBounds options> options? )
```

Something like this should work:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map,layerSource)
    .addTo(map)
    .done(function(layer) {
        var beams = [[34,-122],[14,-100]];

        map.fitBounds(
            beams, 
            {maxZoom: 6, 
             paddingTopLeft: [50, 70], 
             paddingBottomRight: [50, 50]
            });

        map.spin(false);
});
```

It looks like your errors might also come from trying to add a layer to an already-added layer. After createLayer, you chain on `.addTo(map)`... this adds the layer to the map, so there's no need to use the Leaflet `addLayer` method.

Comment: Hi Andy, you are correct I need coordinates. My problem is that named map in cartoDB only provide tiles (http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html#named-maps-1). Can leaflet detect the added tile layer and zoom on its boundaries ?

Comment: For regular map we can use sql.getbounds http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sqlgetboundssql-vars-options-callback

Comment: Nope, that data isn't passed client-side unless you specify it in the config file you use to setup the map. You could probably update the SQL to return these values using `ST_Extent(the_geom)`...